# sum of textboxes with javascript and using comma instead of dot in decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I found a code block on the web that does the sum of textboxes. This block of code looked exactly what I was looking for, but I need to use commas instead of dots for decimal numbers, and I even need to prevent the entry of periods in textboxes. unfortunately my javascript knowledge is very amateur and i don't know how to do this. can you help me with this
thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sum Html Textbox Values using jQuery/JavaScript</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            #summation {
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color:#174C68;
            }
            .txt {
                background-color: #FEFFB0;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: right;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Butter</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Cheese</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Eggs</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Soap</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">Sum :</td>
        <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
 
    });
 
    function calculateSum() {
 
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
 
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/g70a2dz9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the existing code block to use commas instead of dots in decimal numbers and prevent the entry of periods in textboxes as follows:

In the `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     
        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {
    
            //Prevent entry of period in textboxes
            $(this).keypress(function (event) {
                var keyCode = event.which;
                if (keyCode == 46) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
    
            //Replace commas with dots
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                value = value.replace(/,/g, '.');
                $(this).val(value);
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
    
    });
```

The keypress event is added to each textbox to prevent the entry of period (keyCode 46).
The `keyup` event is modified to replace commas with dots, and then trigger the `calculateSum()` function.

In the `calculateSum()` function:

```
function calculateSum() {
    
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
    
            //Replace commas with dots
            var value = $(this).val();
            value = value.replace(/,/g, '.');
    
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(value) && value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(value);
            }
    
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        var sumString = sum.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',');
        $("#sum").html(sumString);
    }
```

The code to replace commas with dots is added for each textbox value.
The final sum is converted back to a string with commas instead of dots using the replace() method.

Comment: Shown with total sum "span" in the script. Is it possible to show it as a textbox instead of a span ?

Comment: To use a `textbox` instead of a `span`, you would need to modify the HTML code to include an input element instead of a span element:
`<td align="center"><input type="text" id="sum"></td>`
Then, in the `calculate()` function, you would need to modify the line that sets the value of the sum to update the value of the `textbox` instead of the `span`:
`$("#sum").val(sumString);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace the dot with a comma, you will need to convert your `sum` (`float`) to a string. Then you can just use the `.replace()` method in order to replace all the dots by commas.

Here is the code:

```
//.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places

    sum = sum.toFixed(2);
    sum.toString();
    sum = sum.replace(".",",");

    $("#sum").html(sum);
```

Comment: Shown with total sum "span" in the script. Is it possible to show it as a textbox instead of a span ?